# How do I remove an element from a state using useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm generating a list of values from checkboxes.

```
const [checkedState, setCheckedState] = useState({});

const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  if(e.target.checked === true){
    setCheckedState({ ...checkedState, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  } else {
    setCheckedState({...checkedState, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked.filter(element => element !== e.target.checked)})
  }    
};
```

When I console log it, I get this `checkedState: {action/adventure: true, documentary: true}, etc.` when I check the boxes. Which is fine! But likewise, I need to remove it from that object, when I uncheck it. So the else portion is my problem.

Realistically, if I unchecked documentary, I should console.log  `checkedState:  {action/adventure: true}`

Comment: e.target.checked is probably not an array, so e.target.checked.filter would throw an error.

Comment: `filter` works on arrays, not objects. If you want to remove a property from an object using spread syntax, set it to undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  if(e.target.checked === true){
    setCheckedState({ ...checkedState, [e.target.name]: e.target.checked });
  } else {
    const copyOfCheckedState = {...checkedState};
    delete copyOfCheckedState[e.target.name];
    setCheckedState(copyOfCheckedState);    
};
```

Alternative using [rest in destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#rest_property). It's a bit harder to grasp when you are not used to the syntax, so I wouldn't advice:

```
 } else {
    const {[e.target.name]: _targetName, ...checkedStateWithoutTargetName} = checkedState;
    setCheckedState(checkedStateWithoutTargetName);    
};
```

#### Note

As @sasi k pointed out it's recommended to use the callback form of `setState` when you depend of the previous state, so you'd rather do something like

```
setCheckedState(checkedState => {
  // return new state
});
```

Comment: When updating state if you need prevState you can't just directly use state variable instead you should use a function. Refer react official docs https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: @sasi k you can actually use the variable directly. There are two cases where you should use a callback : to batch state updates (several updates of the same state sequentially, which doesn't seem to be the case here) and React concurrent mode. The rest is fine. That being said, it's generally encouraged to use the callback form to avoid being tripped when these cases arise, so you are right about this. I'll mention this in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use delete to remove property from object.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete

Ideally if you are updating state using previous state you should do this

```
const handleOnChange = (e) => {
  if (e.target.checked === true) {
     setCheckedState(prevState => ({
       ...prevState,
       [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
     }));
  } else {
      setCheckedState((prevState) => {
         delete prevState[e.target.name];
         return prevState
      })
   }
};
```

Refer React official docs for more info
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates

Comment: After copying `checkedState` then, because modifying state object directly is a bad idea

Comment: Can you elaborate on this please

Comment: I never said to modify state directly. I gave a hint to use delete keyword.

Comment: My bad, I thought you wanted to modify the state variable directly. That being said, I am not 100% that we are supposed to modify the callback argument either. It's probably fine but I don't have enough knowledge to say it with certainty.